# PHP: Array Difference; Multi-Dimensional Array and Secondary Array Keys

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to sort out a multidimensional array based on an array of keys (query params), but am having no luck in doing so.

Array From DB:

```
AOD (Array, 2 elements)
  topic (String, 21 characters ) Alcohol & Other Drugs
  lessons (Array, 29 elements)
CEH (Array, 2 elements)
  topic (String, 25 characters ) Community & Environmental
  lessons (Array, 23 elements)
```

Array of Keys (Query String):

```
0 (String, 3 characters ) AOD
1 (String, 3 characters ) CEH
```

So, if I only passed in `AOD`, then the first array above would only return the multi-dimensional array of `AOD`

Code:

```
array_intersect($snsData, array_flip($query_topics))
```

Comment: What are the `var_dumps` of `$snsData` and `$query_topics`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working Code:**

```
array_intersect_key($snsData, array_flip($query_topics))
```

Where `$query_topics` is an array of $_GET params